# Effect of use Encode qw/encode decode from_to/;?

Tags: perl

What is the effect of this at the top of a `perl` script?

```
use Encode qw/encode decode from_to/;
```

I found this on code I have taken over, but I don't know what it does.

Comment: Character encodings, apparently: [Encode](http://perldoc.perl.org/Encode.html). Core module, too.

Answer (score 1):

**Short story:** for an experienced perl coded who knows what modules are:
The **Encode** module is for converting perl strings to "some other" format (for which there are many sub-modules that define difference formats).  Typically, it's used for converting to and from Unicode formats eg:

```
... to convert a string from Perl's internal format into ISO-8859-1, also known as Latin1:
    $octets = encode("iso-8859-1", $string);
```

`decode` is for going the other way, and `from_to` converts a string from one format to another in place;

```
from_to($octets, "iso-8859-1", "cp1250");
```

**Long story:** for someone who doesn't know what a module is/does:
This is the classic way one uses code from elsewhere.  "Elsewhere" usually means one of two possibilities - either;

1. Code written "in-house" - ie: a part of your private application that a past developer has decided to factor out (presumably) because its applicable in several locations/applications; or
2. Code written outside the organisation and made available publicly, typically from [the Comprehensive Perl Archive Network - CPAN](http://cpan.org)

Now, it's possible - but unlikely - that someone within your organization has created in-house code and co-incidentally used the same name for a module on CPAN so, if you check CPAN by searching for **"Encode"** - you can see that there is a module of that name - and that will almost certainly be what you are using.  You can read about it [here](https://metacpan.org/pod/Encode).

The `qw/.../` stands for *"quote words"* and is a simple short hand for creating a list of strings; in this case it translates to **("encode", "decode", "from_to")** which in turn is a specification of what parts of the `Encode` module you (or the original author) want.

You can read about those parts under the heading **"Basic methods"** on the documentation (or "POD") page I referred earlier.  Don't be put off by the reference to "methods" - many modules (and it appears this one) are written in such a way that they support both an Object Oriented and functional interface.  As a result, you will probably see direct calls to the three functions mentioned earlier as if they were written directly in the program itself.

Comment: Thanks, this information is useful. I didn't know what `qw` was.